# Variable Scope Confusion

Tags: ruby, scope

I am doing Chris Pine Leap Year Example. The question is to write a method that will tell you all the leap years in a range of years. You ask the user for a starting year, and an ending year.

Looking at the provided answer, I am confused on how the `year` variable being looped in the `while` statement is also being added to the statement `puts "Check it out...these years are leap years:"`. I understand the `while` loop. I am not seeing how each year or result is being displayed to the user. Isn't the `year` variable in the `while` statement in a scope separate from that of the `year` in the `puts` statement?

```
def leap_years
  puts "Starting Year?"  
    start = gets.chomp.to_i

  puts "Ending Year?"
    ending = gets.chomp .to_i

  puts "Check it out...these years are leap years:"
    year = start #year is now = to the start, but how is it getting fed each year from the while loop?

while year <= ending
    if year%4 == 0
      if year%100 != 0 || year%400 == 0
        puts year
      end
    end
    year = year + 1
  end 

end
```

Comment: Nope, they are the same variable. Clearly; as the output is being printed.

Comment: Thanks Abizern. I can see that it is somehow the same variable.  I am trying to understand the connection of how each valid year in the while loop is being printed in the last puts statement?

Comment: Print out the statement, take a pencil and follow the path of the code as the variable changes, it should become clear to you.

Comment: I think I got it now. "year" is not being shoveled or passed to the variable up top.  It is just being printed to screen in the while loop, since that is the last line of code being "puts'd" it is going to right below the last puts statement of "puts "Check it out..etc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `puts "Check it out...these years are leap years:"` is only printing the initial message before it goes into the loop. It is not printing any years.
- `year = start` initializes the variable `year` before it goes into the loop.
- Printing each year is done by the line `puts year` inside an `if` loop inside another `if` loop inside the `while` loop, and the `while` loop is inside the scope of variable `year`, and can access it.

By the way, the provided answer that you cite does not look nice. A cleaner solution is as follows:

```
class Fixnum
  def leap_year?
    return true  if modulo(400).zero?
    return false if modulo(100).zero?
    return true  if modulo(4).zero?
    return false
  end
end

puts (start..ending).select(&:leap_year?)
```

Or, more efficiently:

```
(start..ending).each{|i| puts i if i.leap_year?}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the key here is being able to understand two things... Ruby scope and this line: `year = year + 1`

If the concept of scope is unclear, I'd recommend a little googling. "ruby scope" would be a good start.

Here's how I would think about it:

Say `start` is 1, so then we create a new variable called `year` and we set that equal to `start`. So `year` contains 1.

The scope that `year` lives in is that of the function `leap_years` so everything else in `leap_years` that comes after the declaration of `year` can change what `year` contains.

Now, there's that while loop. This while loop lives in the same scope as `year`, as does anything that is inside the while loop.

So you start going through the loop and you get to the line `year = year + 1`. I remember this kind of concept really confusing me when I started programming. If year equals 1 I would read that as "1 = 1 + 1" which is nonsense.

I would now think of that line like so...

`Set our already-existing variable year equal to the current value of year + 1`

So if year = 1 on the first iteration, year now contains 2.

Next time we run through the iteration, since the whole `leap_years` function can reference `year`, in the while loop year will contain 2 and if the conditions are met year will be printed to the screen. `year = year + 1` will execute once again and `year` will then contain 3. All until year contains the same value as ending at which point the while loop stops.